# Javascript retrieve json and POST

Tags: javascript, html, post

Hello guys i am trying to retrieve data in json format which is ok.
But i am having reposting the data to another url.

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
      var formData = {fname:data[0],lname:data[1],email:data[2]};
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    });
    $.ajax({
    url : "http://requestb.in/1k8rvk71",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
     //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
  }); 
  </script>
```

Plz help guys.. really need to get this work.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: What errors does your console / network tab give you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ajax to send data to a different domain than the one your javascript code is served from.

This is called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

There are two possible ways around this restriction:

1. On your server, have a server-side page (in PHP for example) that takes the data and posts it to that remote URL
2. If that remote URL has a [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to submit it client-side
3. [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) - but there's a lot of issues with this cross-browser and server

Comment: @Phil No, I understand I just had a mental block for a second. already updated

Comment: Regarding #3, what issues?

Comment: @Phil "If the server does not allow the cross-origin request, the browser will deliver an error to example-social-network.com page instead of the online-personal-calendar.com response." A lot of servers reject it, so not good to rely on this.

Comment: That entirely depends on the server but in this case you are correct, requestb.in does not set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header though the request still reaches the server and is logged so I'm not sure if that counts as a success or failure